# how to send ethers from 1 account to another using smart contract

Tags: reactjs, solidity, smartcontracts

I have deployed smart contract using Reactjs, ganache and metamask.
I wish to send ether from current account to another account using the deployed contract.
Desired scenario:

I will enter the receiver's address in the front end and it should open up a metamask pop up to send ether to that address. But right now when I implement the function it just initiates a transaction to to the smart contract with some gas and doesnt send anything to the address.
Kindly suggest me the changes needed
Smart Contract Code:

```
function payment (uint amount, address payable beneficiary) payable external {

           
         beneficiary.transfer(amount);
       }
```

React Appjs Code to use this function:

```
function payment(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    
    project.methods.payment(1,'0xe13DC66579940552574Cbe795410423609C2BFd9').send({from: {CurrentAccount}['CurrentAccount']});
       
  }
```

Please suggest the changes needed to send ether to that address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to transfer ether with contract just send your amount of ether in to contract. then get amount of ether with tx.value and transfer it.

```
function payment (address payable beneficiary) payable external{
  uint256 amount = msg.value;
  beneficiary.transfer(amount);
}
```

then in app.js

```
function payment(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress, 'latest');
 const data = project.methods.payment('0xe13DC66579940552574Cbe795410423609C2BFd9').encodeABI();
   
     }
const transaction = {
 'to': 'contract Address',
 'value': 100000000000000000, // the amount of ether you will trasnfer with contract
 'gas': 30000,
 'maxFeePerGas': 1000000108,
 'nonce': nonce,
};
const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction, PRIVATE_KEY);

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction, function(error, hash) {
if (!error) {
  console.log(" The hash of your transaction is: ", hash, "\n Check Alchemy's Mempool to view the status of your transaction!");
} else {
  console.log("❗Something went wrong while submitting your transaction:", error)
}
});
```